# Jquery-number remove trailing zeros after decimal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, masking

Looking for a bit of help on some jquery

I am using jquery.number.js as per blog and github for masking
http://www.teamdf.com/web/196/jquery-number-format-redux

If you have a textbox masked to 4 decimal places
as soon as you type say "100" the decimal and trailing zeros appear
so .0000 would appear automatically

Is it possible to stop this?
Or even delay this happening until you leave the textbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: Thanks for reply, 

Here is a live demo version of it - [link]http://opensource.teamdf.com/number/examples/demo-as-you-type.html[/link]

and the code on Github
[link]https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/blob/master/jquery.number.js[/link]

basically I apply the function

$('#txtbox').number( true, 4 );

Thanks

Comment: JSFiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/796qW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspecting the plugin, i've discover that you can simply do this :

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    this.value = $.number(this.value, 2)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65VF6/

---

## Edit : restrict to 4 decimals :

In the previous code, there was a bug when rewriting a number (comma bug). here the fix :

```
$('#txtbox1').blur(function(){
    this.value = $.number(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''), 4)
});
```

Then, to restrain decimal point, you need an other event on keyup. Like this :

```
$('#txtbox1').blur(function(){
    this.value = $.number(this.value.replace(/,/g, ''), 4)
}).keyup(function() {
    
    var foo = this.value.replace(/(\..{0,4}).*$/, '$1')
    
    var carretPos = doGetCaretPosition(this);
    
    this.value = foo;
    
    setSelectionRange(this, carretPos, carretPos)
});
```

This script use custome function that you can find in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/796qW/3/).

Comment: Hi lads, i jumped the gun a bit
I tested it but it still lets me enter more than the mask
obviously because the mask is only applied onblur()

is there a way within the jquery to only apply zeros when onblur but retain the mask of decimal places

Comment: @Paul you mean like not be able to enter more than 4 digits after the `.`?

Comment: yes @Karl - only enter a max of 4 but not to autofill the zeros

apologies I should have been clearer before

thanks again

Comment: thanks again for your help, its tricky alright 
I started out originally wth ajax masked-extender but it proved to restrictive, 
Besides the small flicker it looks great, 
Thanks again for your help